# Extract script with which data was inserted into an old table and the owner in BigQuery - GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I am trying to find out what was the query run to be able to insert data into an empty table created earlier.
It would also be useful for me to know the user who was the creator of that table, if not, just to ask him about that script.

I tried with "INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES;" but I only get the create script of the table.

Answer (score 0):

I would look into `BigQuery audit logs`

most probably you can get information you want :

here is reference: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/auditlogs/